# JerseyClient property() returns null

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using Jersey 2.25.

I'm trying to set `connectTimeout` and `readTimeout` to a client, but it returns null instead of the Client instance. I'm creating the Client through `ClientBuilder.build()`.

```
ClientBuilder builder = ClientBuilder.newBuilder();
    builder.sslContext(createSSLContext());
    Client client = builder.build();
    client = client.property("jersey.config.client.connectTimeout", 100); //returns null
    client = client.property("jersey.config.client.readTimeout", 100); //returns null
```

Is there any reason to expect property() to return null? How could it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to reassign the `client` instance, just call the methods on the same instance returned from `builder.build()`:

```
Client client = builder.build();
client.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 100);
client.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 100);
...
```